# Pass multiple options to a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have in my page two sliders which share the same options:

```
var options1 = {
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 310,
    itemMargin: 5
}

var options2 = {
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false
}
```

And then I have something like this:

```
$('#carousel').flexslider(options1);
$('#slider').flexslider(options2);

$('#carousel2').flexslider(options1);
$('#slider2').flexslider(options2);
```

The problem is I need to add to the end of the options one option that is different for each one, which is this: `asNavFor: '#slider'` for options1 and `sync: "#carousel"` for options two. I tried this but it didn't work:

```
$('#carousel').flexslider(options1, {asNavFor: '#slider'});
$('#slider').flexslider(options2, {sync: "#carousel"});

$('#carousel2').flexslider(options1, {asNavFor: '#slider2'});
$('#slider2').flexslider(options2, {sync: "#carousel2"});
```

I want to avoid repeating the options because they're the same for every slider. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could look into `Object.assign`

Answer (score 1):

You could to add the attributes to the object before passing it to the `flexslider()` :

```
options1['asNavFor'] = '#slider';
options2['sync'] = '#carousel';

$('#carousel').flexslider(options1);
$('#slider').flexslider(options2);
```

Then override it with new values before second call :

```
options1['asNavFor'] = '#slider2';
options2['sync'] = '#carousel2';

$('#carousel2').flexslider(options1);
$('#slider2').flexslider(options2);
```

You could use for loop like :

```
var nbr_elements = 3;

for(var i=1;i<nbr_elements;i++)
{
    if(i==1){
        options1['asNavFor'] = '#slider';
        options2['sync'] = '#carousel';

        $('#carousel').flexslider(options1);
        $('#slider').flexslider(options2);
    }else{
        options1['asNavFor'] = '#slider'+i;
        options2['sync'] = '#carousel'+i;

        $('#carousel'+i).flexslider(options1);
        $('#slider'+i).flexslider(options2);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, I figured anyways that I can make a for loop and avoid this problem completely (:

Comment: You're weclome, how much carousel/slider you have ? check my update.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to crete a new object with your options as a template:

```
$('#carousel').flexslider(Object.assign({}, options1, {asNavFor: '#slider'}));
$('#slider').flexslider(Object.assign({}, options2, {sync: "#carousel"}));

$('#carousel2').flexslider(Object.assign({}, options1, {asNavFor: '#slider2'}));
$('#slider2').flexslider(Object.assign({}, options2, {sync: "#carousel2"}));
```

If you need to support old browsers you can use jQuery's [`$.extend`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) or a [polyfill](https://github.com/ljharb/object.assign) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answering, but I'll use a foor loop because there may be more than 2 galleries and I can avoid this problem!

Comment: Not sure how that plugin works but perhaps you could use a common class instead of unique ids.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [jQuery's `extend`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) to dynamically create extended options like this:

```
options1Nav1 = $.extend({}, options1, {asNavFor: '#slider'});
options2Sync1 = $.extend({}, options2, {sync: '#carousel'});

options1Nav2 = $.extend({}, options1, {asNavFor: '#slider2'});
options2Sync2 = $.extend({}, options2, {sync: '#carousel2'});
```

and then calling

```
$('#carousel').flexslider(options1Nav1);
$('#slider').flexslider(options2Sync1);

$('#carousel2').flexslider(options1Nav2);
$('#slider2').flexslider(options2Sync2);
```

Of course you can pass the dynamically extended options directly as well.